# Can analog pins be defined as either their analog name (A0) or their digital pin number?

Tags: port-mapping

Can analog pins be defined by their digital pin number, and be used for analog purposes?

For example, instead of defining `A0` for a pinout with the Uno, it could be `14`?

Where is this documented? Is there a PDF type manual related to this, but not so low level to get into the ATmega chip?

[image]

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example, instead of defining A0 for a pinout with the Uno, it could be 14?

Yes. In fact A0 is just a placeholder for the number 14.

For all these things you should look in the `pins_arduino.h` file (Arduino\variants\wifio) for any variant you are interested in. That's where most of these symbols are defined. For example:

```
#define PIN_A0   (14)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A1   (15)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A2   (16)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A3   (17)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A4   (18)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A5   (19)                                                                                   
#define PIN_A6   (20)
#define PIN_A7   (21)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
```

Incidentally, on the Uno you can also just use `0` for A0 with `analogRead()`.

Comment: You can use 0 for A0 only in analogRead.  If you are using it as a digital pin you still have to either call it 14 or A0.

Comment: @Delta_G Good point on the usage distinction.